# Javascript Promises, Returned Promise of then and catch method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Was fooling around a bit with Promises, here is the code:

```js
let prom1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res('res');
});

const resolvedProm1 = prom1.then((val) => {
  return val
});
console.log(resolvedProm1);

let prom2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  rej('rej');
});

const resolvedProm2 = prom2.catch((err) => {
  return err
});
console.log(resolvedProm2);
```

The chrome devtools shows the following information about the promises:

[image: Promises, javascript promises]

However, I didn't expect this particular output. What I expected was the following:

- Both resolvedProm1 and resolvedProm2 would be `<fullfilled>` Promises instead of `<pending>`. Why are they pending and not fullfilled?
- The resolvedProm2 was rejected, why does the promiseStatus shows that it is resolved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543879/using-settimeout-with-no-timeout-value-while-evaluating-result-of-promise-all/52544026#52544026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases promises printed before they are resolved. What you send into promise context will always execute after your current callstack unwinds, so consoles till the end of a function run first.

Answer (score 1):

> Both `resolvedProm1` and `resolvedProm2` would be  Promises instead of . Why are they pending and not fullfilled?

Because they are resolved asynchronously. You were logging them while they still were pending. You'll notice if you put some `console.log` statements in your `then` and `catch` callbacks that the callbacks weren't executed yet as well.

You only get the *[[PromiseStatus]]* as *"resolved"*  (which really should be *"fulfilled*") when you inspect the promise value in the devtools, which you do *after* they were resolved.

> The `resolvedProm2` was rejected, why does the promiseStatus shows that it is resolved?

No, you were rejecting the `prom2`. The `resolvedProm2` is the result of the `.catch()` invocation, whose callback did *handle* the rejection and returned a non-error result.